# Paginação hasMany Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento em meu `Model` Cliente:

```
public function Usuario(){ 
    return $this->hasMany('SIST\Models\Admin\Usuario', 'id_cliente');
}
```

Passo os dados do cliente pelo meu `Controller`:

```
$cliente = Cliente::find($id_cliente);
return view('admin/usuario/index',['cliente' => $cliente]);
```

E faço a listagem de usuários na minha `View`:

```
@foreach($cliente->Usuario as $usuario)
```

Preciso saber como faço para paginar os resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de chamar diretamente o relacionamento, você pode utilizar o método do relaciomanento para poder chamar o paginate.

```
$cliente = Cliente::findOrFail($id_cliente);

$usuarios = $cliente->usuarios()->paginate(15);
```

Na view, você vai substituir `$cliente->usuarios` por `$usuarios` no seu `foreach`.

E para exibir os links da paginação, faça assim na `view`:

```
  {{ $usuarios->links() }}
```

Você também pode usar o método `$usuario->render()` opcionalmente. Esses dois métodos servem para o mesmo propósito.

Comment: É `links()`, `render()` ou `tantofaz()` ?

Comment: Sério ? Está na documentação. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

Comment: É pra mostrar os LINKs de paginação na `view` sim. Uso direto o `render()`.

Comment: Vou ver. Não conheço o `Paginator`. Não quis dizer que você está errado e eu certo. O `links()` chama a `render`. `return $this->render($presenter);`. É só o nome da chamada... valeu!

Comment: @Zoom fiquei preocupar de estar errado. Eu não uso o laravel 5, uso o 4. Mas como dizem por aí que é quase a mesma coisa, me arrisquei a responder :D

Comment: Eu comecei a usar Lavarel no 4.2. Depois que saiu o 5.0... já migrei. O duro é paginação em aparelho móvel.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!